# Ubuntu on ARM Tegra Chromebook (Acer CB5-311)

Tags: acer, chromebook, arm

recently I got a chromebook ACER CB5-311. As the ChromeOS basically is not fully OS I wanted to try installing Ubuntu on SD card. I've tried all the scripts from the github and reddit and they are all outdated and unable to install Ubuntu on SD Card. Is there any up to date instruction to do it? I'm not familiar with script editing so it's really hard for me to get through.

Answer (score 0):

1) Please check your BIOS to make sure the SD card is listed as a boot device; if not, enable it for booting.

2) Follow the Ubuntu instructions at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootFromSD